# R - Date ddmmyyyy and dd/mm/yyyy in same column

Tags: r, date

In the same column, I have dates under the format ddmmyyyy and dd/mm/yyyy. The column is of class character. I would like to convert the dates under the format date.

This is pretty easy separately. But I do not understand how to convert them both.

Another problem I have is that when there is no date at certain rows, it does not appear as "NA" (I also checked with the function `is_empty()`)... So, I cannot separate the dates in two different columns.

Here is what my dataset looks like :

```
date = c("22102002", "23122002", "23/12/02", "29/12/03", ""   ,"04/06/04") 
as.data.frame(date)
```

So I have  :

```
date 
22102002
23122002
23/12/02
29/12/03

04/06/04
```

and I would like :

```
true_date
22/10/2002
23/12/2002
23/12/02
29/12/03
NA
04/06/04
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`.

```
date = c("22102002", "23122002", "23/12/02", "29/12/03", ""   ,"04/06/04") 
as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(date, c('dmY', 'dmy')))
#[1] "2002-10-22" "2002-12-23" "2002-12-23" "2003-12-29" NA           "2004-06-04"
```